Do any denominations teach that Lucifer has a son?
This question states:

Lucifer and God both have a son.

I was un-aware of this belief. Minor googling shows that it may be a belief, but it isn't very clear as there looks to be lots of fiction sources-in that people write books with a Satan/Lucifer character with son/relationship. Where does this belief stem from? Do any denominations teach this? How could Satan even have a son, as my understanding is that he does not have a physical body (or is this a spirit/demon only son)?

I added the LDS tag because that's apparently the only relevant denomination? If there are other denominations that also believe this, then please add that info to the question. The tag should only be removed if there are actually other denominations that believe this. Do remember that Biblical Basis questions have to be about doctrines that are clearly taught by either a denomination or an important Christian individual. We don't allow questions that are simply "is X true?"

@curiousdannii LDS don't believe this though, I'm trying to figure out who does? The question I quote is someone attempting to learn about LDS beliefs, no where does LDS doctrine state Lucifer a) has a body b) has a son. The OP states this as fact, googling shows at least minor/fiction belief of this topic. I want to know if this is doctrinal based or denomination based. Someone made a claim in C.SE question and I saw no-one else question that point, is the claim true?

You really should just be asking that person where they got that idea then. If LDS don't teach this then it can't be a biblical basis question... The best you could do is simply ask if any denominations teach that Satan has a son.

@curiousdannii if the LDS don't teach this then it can't be a biblical basis question, what? I did ask that, and you flagged it LDS, so I flagged it with the denomination of the person who mentioned it. I feel like your comments are not clarifying things.

Biblical basis questions have to be about the teachings of denominations or prominent individuals (for example, Aquinas or Joseph Smith). Someone on this site doesn't qualify. Instead just ask if any denominations teach this.

@curiousdannii I've never associated the biblical basis tag with denomination or prominent individuals (that isn't what the description says). I did ask if any denomination teaches this, and I have re-edited to ask again

Tag descriptions can't say everything. In this case this meta discussion sets out guidelines for the tag: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6008/6071

All the "legalism" of which tag is appropriate aside, I know the question is because of me. So... being totally called out I should provide more info which this question does allow for.

Righto, Orthodox perspectives on things like God and the devil are going to be academically frustrating. After all, how can we clearly define what is either beyond us or the difficulty in rationally explaining something irrational (who would rationally defy God outright?!)
It is of course of value to point out that Satan is not the contemporary figure we typically think of. There is no "man" in "red" or "with a pitchfork" etc.


In fact, the Orthodox Church has never formulated a systematic teaching concerning the Devil, in the form of a clear and concise “doctrine.” What is of paramount importance is that the Church has always had the experience of the demonic, has always, in plain words, known the Devil. If this direct knowledge has not resulted in a neat and orderly doctrine, it is because of the difficulty, if not impossibility, rationally to define the irrational. And the demonic and, more generally, evil are precisely the reality of the irrational. Some theologians and philosophers, in an attempt to explain and thus to “rationalize” the experience and the existence of evil, explained it as an absence: the absence of good. They compared it, for example, to darkness, which is nothing but the absence of light and which is dispelled when light appears. This theory was subsequently adopted by deists and humanists of all shades and still constitutes an integral part of our modern worldview.  The remedy against evil is always seen in “enlightenment” and “education.”  -Alexander Schmemann, "Preparation for Baptism" in "Of water and the Spirit, found within these pages 21-30)

So the first thing I'm addressing with this is that...

The Orthodox Church does not strive to understand or know Satan.
The Orthodox Church holds that Satan, (and his angels) are irrational (Who rejects God on purpose?!)
The Orthodox Church holds a position of being able to identify it.*

*It is similar to that american judge? who said on the subject of "Obscenity" that "I'll know it when I see it"
So, there is no systematic teaching or "neat and orderly" understanding here. I feel like the Catholics who try to have a systematic teaching for every little detail might be more "satisfying" in this regard. But I believe that the Orthodox church's way of not defining everything is actually more valid. (I'm biased towards my faith)


The two worlds—angelic and human—are inseparably linked. The supreme angel, together with his minions, was called to become man’s first friend, and this service could have been based only on self-renouncing love. When this love faded, its place was taken by the lust for power, fed by envy, for, originally, from his creation, man was placed ontologically higher than the angels, having his own world, which the angels serve. From the guardian angel of the world Satan is transformed into “the prince of this world,” who wants to gain possession of it. He becomes a conquering predator, gov­erned not by love but by envy and the lust for power, not by truth but by falsehood. The devil “was a murderer from the beginning, and abode not in the truth, because there is no truth in him” (John 8:44). Satan’s relation to the world is based upon his all-devouring subjectivism, for he finds for himself a kingdom in which he can rule parasitically, until he is “cast out” (John 12:31). As an angel he retains access to the life of the world and his own place of action in it. As Satan he retains this possibility of action in the world, but he uses it now to pervert the world according to his own likeness, to sow his chaff in the world, to poison and ruin the world. As an angel he is not transcendent to the world but belongs to it; as Satan he is hostile to the world. And by this creative capacity of evil, he acquires objective life. If the life of the holy angels is cohu­man by their positive service, then in the case of Satan too it is cohuman, but now only because of parasitic infection. Satan’s insane desire to become God’s equal and to take God’s place in the human world finds a temporary and apparent realization, whence the creative action of evil in the world and the battle for the world with God.  (Bulgakov, Bride, pp. 158-159)

Sub-source: Website article about the demonic void and apokatastasis of satan. written by "Fr Aidan Kimel"
Evil can be very creative, evil "squirms" trying to trick us. Satan copies, twists, perverts, and deceives. Make no mistake we do not understand the almost unending amount of force behind this.

‘there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect.’ (Matt. 24:24)


There is of course the obvious biblical "Antichrist" that we can look at.

"From a defiled virgin will actually be born his (the devil's) weapon." says St. Ephrem the Syrian.


"A man (the Antichrist) will be born from fornication." -St. John of Damascus.

Ultimately however digging into this side of things will lead us down the path of looking at the Tribe of "Dan" who is excluded from the remaining tribes of Israel. (Revelations 6:4-8) As well as various church fathers pointing towards "Dan shall be a serpent on the way, an adder in the path..." (Genesis 49:17)
This is not what was being referenced, but it is 1 instance of a "son of satan" in a very literal sense.

But that isn't what I was referring to, some figure in revelations. I was referring to the fact that the devil "has a son". It is referenced in Genesis 3:15 (the offspring of women and the serpent are referenced here), this verse is also one of the earliest mentions of the "proto" messiah figure... it is also the earliest mention of the evil one's offspring (because we know it wasn't just a serpent)

"Satan is very cunning. Like an artist, he paints sin in attractive colors, increasing its allure." ... " The devil is relentless, as he also had the audacity to tempt Christ Himself, asking the Lord to “fall down and worship” him – Satan! (Matthew 4:9)."


The devil tries to act in secret, unseen by all. He disguises his actions in a masterly way, to have people believe that he does not exist, and that everything that is said about him is mythical or imagined. He covertly leads people astray with this deception (see 2 Thessalonians 2:10). The Lord has warned us that “the devil is a liar and the father of lies” (John 8:44).

Source for both above: Metropolitan of Pisidia Sotirios: Temptations of the Evil Spirit


Demons, when they are allowed to do so by God — because they can only do what God allows them to do, and no more — can visibly manifest themselves into any form or object. They can visibly appear as Christ, the Mother of God, the saints, an angel of light (2 Corinthians 11:14), and literally any other thing. [See Fr Seraphim Rose’s seminal work, Orthodoxy and the Religion of the Future]


...Having lived this way for 7 years, the ascetic sat down one night to rest after prayer. Suddenly his cell was illuminated with a bright light and many demons appeared to him under the guise of beautiful radiant youths. The false angels pointed to the one of them blazing especially brightly. “Isaac! Here is Christ! Fall down before Him and worship Him.”
Not recognizing the devil’s trick and forgetting to cross himself, the recluse worshipped the imaginary Christ... (Part of the account of Venerable Isaac of the Caves)

Now... perhaps there is no concrete proof of a "son of satan", but there is eyewitness evidence of demons appearing as Christ and other demons appearing as bright beings, and of course lying about who they are.
For our mortal side of things, whether or not satan actually has a son is moot. He will claim to be God, he will lie to us, he will attempt to claim anything God has promised us as from himself. This includes phrases such as "This is my son"...

I should go rephrase that question I guess. looks sheepish

I really like that perspective on Satan. I will say as a Protestant I find the Catholic systematizing far less satisfying.

There are multiple definitions of the word "son" (and by extension "daughter") as used in the scriptures. Not all are applicable, but I think these ones are worth mentioning:

The immediate, literal, familial child of a parent
The extended, distant descendants of someone in the past - for example, "The sons of Adam"
One who is adopted into a family (thus they were not 1 & 2 at first, but then literally 1 & 2)
The manner of respect between one person to another (i.e. a professor or older individual to a student or younger person)
One who is converted or educated by another
One who is the creator of something (i.e. "The father of the light bulb is Thomas Edison")
One who possesses the qualities of someone - a Hebraism meaning "partaker in the qualities of". In this case it does "not mean physical descent from"

In addition, we must account for whether such definitions mean a tangible, physical being ("in the flesh"), or they refer to a spiritual being - one who has not yet, or may have already been, present here on the earth.
Latter-day Saints believe that Satan was a spirit son of God who once had authority in Heaven, but he rebelled against God and was thrust out of heaven, receiving no Body. Joseph Smith taught:

The great principle of happiness consists in having a body. The devil has no body, and herein is his punishment. He is pleased when he can obtain the tabernacle of man, and when cast out by the Savior he asked to go into the herd of swine, showing that he would prefer a swine’s body to having none.

Latter-Day Saints also believe that before Adam and Eve came to the Earth, there were no physical children or future family. Elder Holland said:

...I do know these two were created under the divine hand of God, that for a time they lived alone in a paradisiacal setting where there was neither human death nor future family, and that through a sequence of choices they transgressed a commandment of God which required that they leave their garden setting but which allowed them to have children before facing physical death.

So, if the definition of "Son" is to refer to a physical, literal descendant (#1, #2, and possibly #3), then no, Satan does not have any children.
Now, there are several scriptures which contain phrases such as "sons of the devil", the phrase Sons of Belial, or "of your father the Devil", in John 8:44. In these instances, it is referring to definition #4, 5, and #7
Thus, Satan does not have literal, physical (you might even say genetic) children. However, in the sense that children means followers, believers, or those who show his attitudes, he has many "children".

Do any denominations teach that Lucifer has a son?
The short answer is no.
The Scriptures speak of Satan as having children, but theses passages are speaking in a metaphorical sense and not an actual physical sense. Spirit cannot beget another spirit or a physical person either man or woman. This is metaphysically impossible.

The field is the world, and the good seed is the sons of the kingdom. The weeds are the sons of the evil one. Matthew 13:38


You are of your father the devil, and your will is to do your father's desires. He was a murderer from the beginning, and does not stand in the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he lies, he speaks out of his own character, for he is a liar and the father of lies. - John 8:44


And you were dead in the trespasses and sins 2 in which you once walked, following the course of this world, following the prince of the power of the air, the spirit that is now at work in the sons of disobedience— 3 among whom we all once lived in the passions of our flesh, carrying out the desires of the body and the mind, and were by nature children of wrath, like the rest of mankind. - [Ephesians 2:1-3](https://www.bible gateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202%3A1-3&version=ESV)

St. Thomas Aquinas who is venerated in the Catholic Church and the Anglican Communion has the following to say about Satan


** The Substance of the Angels**

Creatures exist in a series of grades. They participate and represent the goodness of God in various ways. In the world about us, there are three kinds of substances: mineral, vegetal, animal. These are all bodily substances. We find also in this world the human substance which is mineral, vegetal, and animal, and yet is something more; it is not all bodily; man has a spiritual soul. To round out the order of things, there must be some purely spiritual or nonbodily substances. Thus createdsubstances are: the completely bodily substance, the substance that is a compound of body and spirit, and the completely spiritual substance. Completely spiritual substances are called angels.

A bodily substance is composed of two substantial elements, primal matter and substantial form. In angels there is no compounding of matter and form. Matter does not exist in angels; they are pure substantial forms. That is to say, they are pure spirits; they are spirits with no admixture of matter in them.

Holy Scripture (Dan. 7:10) indicates the existence of a vast multitude of angels: "Thousands of thousands ministered to Him, and ten thousand times a hundred thousand stood before Him." Indeed, since the intention back of creation is the perfection of the universe as sharing and representing the divine goodness, it appears that the more perfect creatures should abound in largest multitude. It is, therefore, reasonable to suppose that angels exist in a multitude far exceeding the number of material things.

In bodily substances we distinguish their species or essential kind, and their status as individuals of that kind. For example, we distinguish in a man, (a) what makes him a human being, and (b) what makes him this one human being. Now, that which constitutes a thing in its species or essential kind is called the principle of specification. And that which constitutes a thing as this one item or instance of its kind is called the principle of individuation. In all creatures, the principle of specification is the substantial form which makes the creature an existing thing of its essential kind. And the principle of individuation is matter or bodiliness inasmuch as it is marked by quantity. Since angels have in them no matter or bodiliness at all, for they are pure spirits, they are not individuated. This means that each angel is the only one of its kind. It means that each angel is a species or essential kind of substantial being. Hence each angel is essentially different from every other angel.

The angels are incorruptible substances. This means that they cannot die, decay, break up, or be substantially changed. For the root of corruptibility in a substance is matter, and in the angels there is no matter.

ANGELS AND BODIES

Angels have no bodies. An intellectual nature (that is, a substantial essence equipped for understanding and willing) does not require a body. In man, because the body is substantially united with the spiritual soul, intellectual activities (understanding and willing) presuppose the body and its senses. But an intellect in itself, or as such, requires nothing bodily for its activity. The angels are pure spirits without a body, and their intellectual operations of understanding and willing depend in no way at all upon material substance.

That the angels sometimes assume bodies is known from Holy Scripture. Angels appeared in bodily form to Abraham and his household; the angel Raphael came in the guise of a young man to be the companion of the younger Tobias.

In bodies thus assumed, angels do not actually exercise the functions of true bodily life. When an angel in human form walks and talks, he exercises angelic power and uses the bodily organs as instruments. But he does not make the body live, or make it his own body.  - Angels: From the Teachings of Saint Thomas Aquinas



Although the Orthodox have a less systematic process of theological understanding and doctrine, it remains clear that they have a similar perspective on the understanding of of Satan and the Demonic.
